# IOS | Display several self-chosen locations on a map

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-maps

I'm working on my first IOS app and I need to display a map where the user can see their current location and several locations specified by me in the form of pins or so.
Would also be cool if they could immediately plan a route to these locations.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You display a map on iOS with [MKMapKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497), an official library that allows you to add Apple Maps to your app. You can also set pins ([MKPointAnnotation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW33)) and do routing ([MKDirections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW5) API) with that.

There is a Ray Wenderlich tutorial covering the basics of MapKit here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial